# Differential of $\langle f,g \rangle $, if $f,g: E\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are differentiable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f,g: E\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are differentiable real functions. Prove that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left\langle f(t),g(t) \right\rangle=\left\langle f(t), \frac{d}{dt}g(t) \right\rangle +\left\langle \frac{d}{dt}f(t), g(t) \right\rangle$$

How can I prove that? I know that if $f,g: U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions, so $$d(fg)=fd(g)+gd(f)$$ Can I use it?

Comment: Would it help to write $\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(t)g_i(t)$ where $f(t)=(f_1(t),\ldots,f_m(t))$ etc.?

Comment: is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the usual inner product or general?

Comment: it is inner product general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is exactly the same as the proof of the product formula:
\begin{align} \frac d{dt} \langle f(t), g(t) \rangle 
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\langle f(t+h), g(t+h) \rangle - \langle f(t), g(t) \rangle}{h}
\\&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\langle f(t+h), g(t+h) \rangle - \langle f(t+h), g(t) \rangle}{h} + \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\langle f(t+h), g(t) \rangle- \langle f(t), g(t) \rangle}{h}
\\&= \left\langle \lim_{h\to 0} f(t+h), \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(t+h) - g(t) }{h}\right\rangle + \left\langle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(t+h) - f(t)}{h}, g(t) \right\rangle
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The inner product is bilinear. Hence its differential is given by

$$(\langle u,v\rangle)^\prime(h,k)= \langle u,k\rangle +\langle h,v\rangle$$

This works in finite and infinite dimensionnal spaces providing the inner product is continuous. This is then true for whatever the inner product is. Not only the standard one.